# Can't center an paragraph inside ::before div

Tags: html, css, sass

```css
div.st-header-image {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #a7b885;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.st-header-image p.st-description {
  margin: 0px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div.st-header-image ::before {
  content: " ";
  padding-top: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="st-header-image">
        <p class="st-description">Header Image</p>
</div>
</body>
```

I am trying to make a paragraph that needs to be inside div that have ::before style as well so it changes size when I increase or decrease the resolution.

I try using different overflows, different display... Also tried to fix it using calc((100% - 40px) / 2) for positioning top/bottom but it doesn't seem to work either.

```
div.st-header-image
  {
    width:100%;
    background-color: rgb(167, 184, 133);
    margin:0px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;

      p.st-description
      {
          margin:0px;
          color:red;
          font-size:40px;
          line-height: 40px;
          vertical-align: middle;
      }
      ::before
      {
        content: " ";
        padding-top: 40%;
        display: inline-block;
      } 
  }
```

p element is inside of div with class st-header-image

Div is responsive but paragraph keeps showing under the div instead in center of it...

Comment: Provide a [mcve] (this will need to include a minimum of HTML to demonstrate the problem) and present it as a [live demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Is this in sass?

Comment: If you want to really center, just try `div { display: flex } div p { margin: auto }` it will simplify your approach a lot. Then just add some padding to either the div or the p element. You should, however, add your HTML here and convert the code you tried into a snippet so we can see what you consider wrong.

Comment: @Doc-Han yeah...

Comment: @Quentin I added

Comment: @somethinghere if I do that my box is no longer responsive to screen change...

Comment: Be sure to set `html, body, div { height: 100%; } div { width: 100%; }` to make sure there is space for your box to claim. Then the centering should work like a charm.

Comment: I I'm getting you right, do you want the text in p to be vertically centered in the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to accomplish is to have the div with a responsive space on top and also the paragraph sticking to the middle during it's responsiveness.
I fixed you code without the `::before` pseudo element.

This same feature can be attained using a padding for the div and a little positioning.

I shared the code on repl.it [here](https://repl.it/repls/ForthrightInferiorAccounting)

### Here is the CSS you need:

```css
div.st-header-image {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #a7b885;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 40%;
  position: relative;
}

p.st-description {
  margin: 0px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works like a charm... I gave up on it and went with static height instead of responsive one but this one fixes the problem perfectly... Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, i assume you are using CSS Preprocessor SASS. With that you need to append "p" element before "::before" selector

```
**p::before** {
        content: " ";
        padding-top: 40%;
        display: inline-block;
      }
```

or you can include it using ampersand like this

```
 p.st-description
      {
          margin:0px;
          color:red;
          font-size:40px;
          line-height: 40px;
          vertical-align: middle;

      &::before
      {
        content: " ";
        padding-top: 40%;
        display: inline-block;
      } 
}
```

Comment: ::before is for div not paragraph... So div change size on screen resolution change.

Comment: However, `::before` on its own, not attached to an element, is meaningless and wont show up. So attach it to either the `div` or the `p`, dont do `div ::before`, do `div::before`

Comment: Yea I fix that but still the same result... Might be the problem me trying to write 'Header Image' in image padding basically...

Answer (score 0):

You should use display flex . its allows always center position.

use this code.

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div class="st-header-image">
        <p class="st-description">Header Image</p>
</div>
</body>
```

**css**

```
div.st-header-image {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #a7b885;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.st-header-image p.st-description {
  margin: 0px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  display:flex;
  display:-webkit-flex;
  align-items:center;
  -webkit-align-items:center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
}

div.st-header-image ::before {
  content: " ";
  padding-top: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```